# how to tell a javascript web app to always watching to the change of state of a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

I'm trying to learn reactive programming. I'm simulating the change of a boolean variable in time. The idea is that, I wouldn't know when it is going to change, but I want the app to execute a console.log saying that the variable is true, each time it changes from `false` to `true`. I did this:

```
let x = false

setInterval(function(){ 
   x = !x;
 }, 3000);
```

I can't figure out the approach to tell the app to be watching at the `x` variable's state and a fire `console.log("now it's true")` each time `x == true`.

What could be the simplest way to achieve it? I think I could do it using observables, however, I'm kind of stuck.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that no one uses "reactive programming" by writing it in pure js :) There are a lot of libraries, for example React, Vue, Angular, which implement reactivity.

There are base approaches on which, I think so, every reactivity implementation in JS is built on:

- make a wrapper, for example like this:

```
  const obj = {
    x: true,
    setX(value) {
      this.x = value;
      // You can track x value here
    },
  };

  obj.setX(false);
```

- using getters and setters from es5 specification, here is an example:

```
const obj = {
  _x: 5,
  get x() {
    return this._x;
  },
  set x(value) {
    this._x = value;
    // You can track x value here
  },
};

obj.x = 6;
```

- using proxy from es6 specification - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy;

Comment: could you provide me an example working snippet, please?

Comment: What did you mean? In my answer I already did it. You could paste this fragments of code in any JS playground and see the result :)  If you want example to proxy, well on mdn they are exists. If you want to become a real skill programmer you should advance your skill in working with any kind of documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new with reactive programming as well.

I'd say you are correct to use the observable.
Instead of your setInterval just setting x = !x, have it do something like this

**e.g.** I did not run it.

```
private xSubject = new ReplaySubject<any> (bufferSize:1);
private xReadySubject: Observable<any> = this.xSubject.asObservable();

...
// In the setInterval 
this.xSubject.next(!x);

xReadySubject.subscribe(argX => {
 console.log("Value of x: " + argX
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it is working

```js
let x = false

setInterval(function(){ 
   x = !x;
console.log(x);
 }, 1000);
```